# Unhandled rejection MongoError: CMD_NOT_ALLOWED: mapreduce

Tags: mapreduce, mongodb-atlas

i'm trying to use mapReduce method in  a free [Mongodb-atlas-cloud](https://cloud.mongodb.com/) plan but i got this error

```
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:547:20)
Unhandled rejection MongoError: CMD_NOT_ALLOWED: mapreduce
at Function.MongoError.create ...
```

note: i can write and read without any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from MongoDB Cloud Services Support

> Mapreduce is not allowed in free tier at this moment.
>   https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/unsupported-commands/